# Left join a table on itself to collect rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to write a view which "rotates" a table's data from vertical to horizontal:

```
Uid    Name    Key     Value
 1      User1   data1   resultX
 2      User1   data2   resultY
 3      User1   data3   resultZ
 4      User2   data1   resultX
 5      User2   data3   resultZ
```

The resulting data set should look like this:

```
Name     Val1       Val2       Val3
 User1    resultX    resultY    resultZ
 User2    resultX    NULL       resultZ
```

The tricky thing is that I also want to display empty value fields.
The only way I could more or less achieve this was with sub selects like this
(More or less means: This only works for data sets where a key=data1 is present):

```
SELECT 
    t1.name
    , t1.value AS val1
    , t2.value AS val2 
    , t3.value AS val3 
FROM (
    SELECT
        name
        , value
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        key = 'data1'
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        name
        , value
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        key = 'data2'
) t2
    ON t1.name= t2.name
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        name
        , value
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        key = 'data3'
) t3
    ON t1.name= t3.name
;
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its for known set of items like `data1,data2 and data3` in your case, you can use the following technique

```
select 
name,
max(case when `key` = 'data1' then value end) as val1,
max(case when `key` = 'data2' then value end) as val2,
max(case when `key` = 'data3' then value end) as val3  
from tableA group by name ;
```

Comment: I'm so stupid :) Couldn't see the wood for the trees... Well, the max() is a little bit special.